# redirecting to controller class from popup window

Tags: javascript, spring

I am using Spring controller, jsp as view with javascript and html as front end view. I have popup window, When I submit the button, it should redirect to controller class.

JavaScript code with html:

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
      });
    });
    loginQB = function(){
        var win = window.open('about:blank', 'popup', 'width=640,height=580,resizeable,scrollbars');
        <!-- win.document.write('<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>');
        win.document.write('<form:form id="qblogin" method="POST" action="/asi/mappings">');--!>
        win.document.write('<br>Sign in with Intuit Account or <a href="www.intuit.com">CreateOne</a>');
        win.document.write('<br><input type="text" name="userName">');
        win.document.write('<br><input type="password" name="password">');
        win.document.write('<br><input type="submit" value="Submit">');
        <!--win.document.write('</form>');-->
    }
    </script>
    </head> 
<body>
 <form:form id="qblogin" method="POST" onsubmit="loginQB(); return false;">
   <select name="quickbooks" id="qb" >
    <option value="qb-1">Books Desktop</option>
  </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">        
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring controller class:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("mappingSession")
public class MappingsController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/mappings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String dataMappings(Model model) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Comment: Can you put your form in a separate html and just use the url parameter `window.open('path/to/your/popup.html', . . `.

Comment: I just don't know if you can process your template and `write` it, maybe with the right escape techniques but it would probably be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why don't you use Bootstrap Modal for your pop up.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Secondly, when you submit, you can get the information from your form, serialize it and then pass it to the controller.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

I strongly recommend you to change the implementation of your popup.